# Panel data in Python set index

Tags: python, panel-data

I´m spending a lot of time trying to set my panel data.

Everytime that I run the  following command `df.set_index(['id', 'datas']` I have the message that "None of ['id', 'datas'] are in the columns", as show below, but they are.

What´s happening? Someone can help me?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-219574cda450> in <module>
      1 # Configurando o painel
----> 2 df.set_index(['id', 'datas'], inplace=True)
      3 
      4 # Realizando a regressão POLS
      5 X_pols = df[['perc_qtd_neg_lei', 'ampl_log_0', 'distperc_vwap_inicio_lei', 'segunda', 'terca', 'quarta', 'sexta']]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   4549 
   4550         if missing:
-> 4551             raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
   4552 
   4553         if inplace:

KeyError: "None of ['id', 'datas'] are in the columns"
```

Comment: It looks like you're encountering a KeyError when trying to set the index of your DataFrame using the df.set_index(['id', 'datas'], inplace=True) command. It looks like you're encountering a KeyError when trying to set the index of your DataFrame using the df.set_index(['id', 'datas'], inplace=True) command. Double-check that the column names 'id' and 'datas' are spelled correctly and exactly match the names in your DataFrame.

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.columns)`?